# "Expected an argument name for root field" - how to fix this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, relayjs

In my React app I'm trying to use [Relay](https://facebook.github.io/relay/) to fetch a document (`artwork`) via id, but I'm getting an error:

```
Invariant Violation: printRelayOSSQuery(): Expected an argument name for root field `artwork`.
```

I'm using [graffiti-mongoose](https://github.com/RisingStack/graffiti-mongoose) as the server and my route is based on a sample Relay code, source below:

```
class SubmittedArtworkRoute extends Relay.Route {
  static queries = {
    artwork: (Component) => Relay.QL`
      query {
        artwork(id: $id) {
          ${Component.getFragment('artwork')}
        }
      }
    `,
  };
  static paramDefinitions = {
    id: {required: true},
  };
  static routeName = 'SubmittedArtworkRoute';
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Do you pass in the variable `id` somewhere ? If not this is probably why you're getting the error. You can try adding:
`params: { id: '123', }` to your route

Comment: Yes, I'm passing the `id` when the Relay.Route object is being instantiated, e.g.: `new SubmittedArtworkRoute({id: "123..."})` .

Comment: In general, if I replace this query with a regular query (on viewer type) that doesn't contain a variable, all works ok.

Comment: @AndrewRunner what is the schema definition for the `artwork` field? what is the type of its `id` argument?

Comment: @JoeSavona `id` field is created with the `globalIdField` Relay helper, which uses `GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLID)` internally. Details for `globalIdField`: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-relay-js/blob/afe4e8eff4d0e7ded7e554a47327ecebb0815112/src/node/node.js#L110-Lundefined